# Cannot use Class Device in a Form

Tags: c#, directx

i do want to access to create an instance of the class 'Device' from DirectX. like in this example : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153258(v=vs.85).aspx
But i have this error : `The type or namespace name 'Device' could not be found.` 
I really searched my problem but didn't find anything usefull. I have imported the Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll from C:\Windows\Microsft.NET... 
But nothing happenned, so if you can help me that would be really awesome !

If you want the code :

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Device device = null;
...
```

Comment: Why? You may save yourself some pain picking more recent tools that match what you actually want to achieve (rather than Managed DX9 that is more than 10 years old)...

Comment: How ? is there any new 'tools' or class to use instead of Device ?

Comment: The Device class is in the Microsoft.DirectX.DirectDraw namespace.  You don't have a *using* directive for it.  But yes, these managed wrappers have been deprecated a very long time ago.  No future, consider SlimDX or SharpDX instead.

Comment: R00t - since you did not say what you *actually trying to do*, but instead "use `class Device`" it is not really possible to suggest alternatives... Something ranging from regular `Bitmap` to Unity3d or new DX wrappers Hans Passant suggested could work.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll use SharpDX instead i think

Answer (score 0):

you must put DirectSound.Device = null;

Comment: Where should this line go?